# Angle between A vector and B vector from given data: $\ |A-B|=\sqrt{3}\ |A|$

Tags: vectors

The two vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ are of equal magnitude and such that $|\vec{A}-\vec{B}|=\sqrt{3}\ |\vec A|$. The angle between $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ is:

(A) $60°\ \ $ (B) $90°\ \ $ (c) $120°\ \ $ (D) $150°$.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please learn how to format your questions. It is not hard. Links to pdfs that are slow to download are tiresome for those who might help you. Also please include brief details of what you have tried. People are reluctant simply to do your homework! I have copied your question and formatted it for you. If you click edit you will see how it is done.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Notice that $|A-B|>|A|=|B|$, so which options can you immediately rule out?

Comment: Drawing a picture of $ \ \vec{A} \ - \ \vec{B} \ $ would help with this quite a bit:  you will have some sort of isosceles triangle and you can almost _guess_ the answer correctly from that...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You may suppose $\lvert\overrightarrow A\rvert=\lvert\overrightarrow B\rvert=1$. Then use *Al Kashi's formula*.

Answer (score 0):

$\left|\, \vec{A}-\vec{B}\,\right|^2=|\vec{A}|^2+|\vec{B}|^2-2|\vec{A}||\vec{B}|\cos(\theta)$

$3|\vec{A}|^2=2|\vec{A}|^2(1-\cos(\theta))$

Solve for $\theta\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 
$$\vec{A}-\vec{B}=\sqrt{3}\ \vec A$$

You got

$$|\vec{A}-\vec{B}|=\sqrt{3}\ |\vec A|$$

Take cross product with B.

$$\vec B X(\vec{A}-\vec{B})=\sqrt{3}\ \vec B X \vec A $$

Can you take it up next?